# AWS Lambda cannot connect to Oracle Instant Client

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, oracle11g, aws-lambda, rhel7

I have a basic requirement of connecting an on premise Oracle database to Redshift.

I need to use AWS Lambda to connect to both the databases using python. While I achieved connection to Redshift by exporting Linux libraries of `psycopg2`, I am facing issues with the Oracle database.

Below are the steps followed to try to connect to Oracle on premise DB :

1. Installed cx_Oracle which came up with cx_Oracle.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so and psycopg2-2.7.4.dist-info
2. Installed basic oracle client lite 64 bit for linux
3. Set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to point to the lib files of the instant client package

When we zip our python file with the dependencies of cx_Oracle and Instant client, AWS Lambda fails with below error :

> "DPI-1047: 64-bit Oracle Client library cannot be loaded: \"libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory\"

Answer (score 0):

From within your lib folder, do:

```
ln -s libclntsh.so.12.1 libclntsh.so
```

(or similar, depending what versions you're using).